# TFS 2005. I lost my Workspace mapping. Dont want to lose checked out work

Tags: tfs, mapping, synchronization, workspace, tfs-2005

I mistakenly wiped out my workspace mapping to my local folder.  No my solutions all say they are not downloaded, but the code is still there of course.  I've got worked checked out.  How do I make this right, or even can I?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remap your workspace like described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: I did recreate it.  But source control doesn't recognize what I have already, it's telling me nothing is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything, *back up your code* - copy it to a folder outside of your mapped workspace folders. That way, if anything goes wrong, you won't lose your code.

The worst case scenario if you do this is then:

- Fix your mappings and Force get all the code (so you lose your changes)
- Copy your backup files back over the source code
- Get locks on your changed files (Either: a) Check out everything, then undo check out, but say "no all" to the question about throwing away changes. This will leave you with locks only on files that have changed)  or b) Go Offline (unplug your net cable, run VS, and it'll go offline) then go online (plug in net cable, File > Source Control > Go Online) and TFS should auto discover your chnaged files)